# GCP Terraform Forwarding Rule Target

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Hey Terraform friends;

Trying to navigate my way through some basic load balancing in the GCP environment. First time doing it, so, still trying to pick up on some of the nuances between the various types and environments.

My goal is to have a target pool of hosts be the destination recipient for connections made to the forwarding rule, in whatever load balancing policy the business needs.

The setup is a bit awkward, because I have the project that I'm doing the work in, but the destination subnetworks are in a shared VPC in another project. Now, according to powers that implemented, the project has permissions to use that subnetwork, which, so far is accurate (I've deployed compute instances to it).

Here's my code:

```
#target pool
resource "google_compute_target_pool" "target_pool" {
    name                = "${var.name}-pool"
    instances           = var.instances
    session_affinity    = var.session_affinity

}

resource "google_compute_address" "lb_address" {
    name            = "${var.name}-load-balancer"
    address_type    = "INTERNAL"
    address         = "10.129.48.250" //cause fuck it I'm trying to figure it out
    subnetwork      = data.google_compute_subnetwork.gcp_subnetwork.name
    project         = var.subnetwork_project
}

#load balancer
resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "basic_load_balancer" {
    name        = var.name
    target      = google_compute_target_pool.target_pool.id
    ip_address  = google_compute_address.lb_address.address
    port_range  = join(",", var.port_range)
    labels      = var.labels
    subnetwork  = data.google_compute_subnetwork.gcp_subnetwork.name
    project     = var.subnetwork_project
    load_balancing_scheme = var.lb_scheme
}
```

With the relevant data:

```
data "google_compute_subnetwork" "gcp_subnetwork" {
    name = var.subnetwork
    project = var.subnetwork_project
}
```

And variables:

```
variable "name" {
    description     = "Name of the application usage"
    type            = string
}

variable "port_range" {
    description     = "List of ports to load balance"
}

variable "port_range_health" {
    description     = "List of ports to health check"
    type            = list(string)
    default         = [ "" ]
}

variable "instances" {
    description = "List of Instances by Zone/Name value"
    type            = list(string)
}

variable "backup_instances" {
    description = "List of Instances by Zone/Name value for backup use"
    type = list(string)
    default = []
}

variable "session_affinity" {
    description     = "Load balancer session affinity type"
    type            = string
    default         = "NONE"
}

variable "labels" {
    description = "Labels to apply to the load balancer"
    type = map
    default = {}
}

variable "lb_scheme" {
    description = "What the LB Forwarding rule is to be used for"
    type = string
    default = "INTERNAL"
}

variable "subnetwork" {
    description = "What network the load balancer should be deployed into"
    type = string
}

variable "subnetwork_project" {
    description = "Project that contains the subnetwork to deploy into"
    type        = string
    default     = ""
}

variable "project" {
    description = "Project supplied by user"
    type        = string
}
```

My subnetwork project is set to the project id of my shared VPC, and I specify the name of the subnetwork. Instance

And when I try to apply, I keep getting hit with an error message about the structure of the target:

```
Error: Error creating ForwardingRule: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'projects/insight-dev-272215/regions/us-central1/targetPools/insight-dev-pool'. The URL is malformed. Must be a valid In-Project Target Proxy URL or a supported Google API bundle., invalid
│
│   with module.insight_solr_lb.google_compute_forwarding_rule.basic_load_balancer,
│   on ..\..\..\modules\load_balancer\gcp\basic\main.tf line 29, in resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "basic_load_balancer":
│   29: resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "basic_load_balancer" {
│
```

I've beaten my head around a few times for a few things, but I'm not making much progress. Anyone experienced in the GCP Forwarding rules see my issue?

I've tried to pass the URI of the target group to the `target`, but it didn't like that either.

Thanks!